# Sqllite PEG parser to support BigQuery SQL syntax

Tags: sql, peg

I'm using [SqLite Parser](https://github.com/codeschool/sqlite-parser/edit/master/src/grammar.pegjs) to parse my SQL to JSON. We are now using Google BQ and some SQL commands are failing in this parser, for example:

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

This can be easily reproduced by using [PEG online](https://pegjs.org/online) which generate this error on the above SQL

> Line 1, column 15: Expected Semicolon or end of input but "(" found.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context into the problem?

Comment: If you go to PEG online and paste on the parser (left-hand side) the code from SqLite parser and the sql I provided in my example you will get an error.
Looking for a way to update the parser to support this query.

Answer (score 2):

Try [node-sql-parser](https://github.com/peg-parser/node-sql-parser/).

It has [bigquery.pegjs](https://github.com/peg-parser/node-sql-parser/blob/master/pegjs/bigquery.pegjs)